# How to resolve an error with PhpExcel in CodeIgniter to read the date in Excel file?

Tags: phpexcel

```
   //load the excel library
    $this->load->library('excel');

    //read file from path
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);

    //get only the Cell Collection
    $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();

    //extract to a PHP readable array format
    foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
        $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
        $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
        $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();

        //header will/should be in row 1 only. of course this can be modified to suit your need.
        if ($row == 1) {
            $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
        } else {
            $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
        }
    }
```

This is my reader code. I'm not able to read the date in my Excel file using this code; it's returning the code like 030567 some thing.

My Excel file has the date value but this code is not returning the date. I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use format like below code:

```
getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue())->format('m/d/Y');
```

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Or you can also try this:

```
$data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
$phpDateTimeObject = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($data_value);
echo phpDateTimeObject->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Just use this code whenever you want date, Just you need to pass the value and you will get date format.  '$phpDateTimeObject = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($data_value);' once you having $phpDateTimeObject then use formatter like phpDateTimeObject->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: this is also not working this function is returning the current date

Comment: First check whether $data_value is returning correct value or not otherwise you will always get default date.

Comment: yea its returning the current value bacause rest every value is coming perfectly...these date only giving the problem